# c#, unity - caroutines, threads, logic, programm structure

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, logic

I did some research on threads and caroutines and I don't know how to "bite" the programming problem I have:

I need to run simultainously character AI's in a simple game - and I need to be able to freeze/pause their execution for a specified time as well as thraw/unpause.
I also need to run a foreach function that will take characters from a list and create a running AI for each of them, as well as beign able to create new AI on demand (by passing constructors).

Perhaps thats a simple thing, but I have no experience, please help.

Comment: What is your exactly problem? Show us some Code. Your Awnser shows no effort for doing anything. Also Unity3D is `Component-Based` Architecture, so making a script which moves multiply  GameObjects` simultainously shouldn't be that challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity you won't have to think too much about threads and such to create a simultaneous behaviour. For example; you create a GameObject, Enemy, with a script to follow another GameObject; Player, which has a script that takes in movement from you. Every Object in the scene with a script will run simultaneous, without any need for Threads and such. There can be, for instance, 5 GameObjects "Enemy" with the same script `EnemyFollowPlayer.cs` and it will run as 5 different EnemyFollowPlayer simultaneous. Coroutines are if you want a threaded behaviour within ONE single script and can be very useful, but is not needed for the most basic things.

[I made a quick GIF to illustrate how Unity handles simuntaneous execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaJw0.jpg) if it's unclear from my description. Since you seem to have the wrong thinking about unitys component based architecture.

In this GIF you see Test.cs, which causes the GameObject it is attached to to move x + 0.001 every time `void Update()` is run, which Unity runs for us every frame. We see how it works on 1 GameObject, and when we copy that GameObject, we see that it runs at the same time on 2 GameObjects without any need for Coroutines, Threads or anything of the like.

Coroutines are great to run code async! Unity comes with some handy features in these as well. Check this example:

```
void SomeNormalMethod() {
    StartCoroutine(AsyncMethod());
    Debug.Log("I will Log first");
}

IEnumerator AsyncMethod() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    Debug.Log("Then after 3 seconds, I will Log!");
}
```

A Coroutine must be a method of type IEnumerator, which gives us access to the `yield` functionality. With this we can use the Unity functionality WaitForSeconds (among other things) to have this asyncronous code wait for a few seconds before doing something, without interrupting the SomeNormalMethod() from continuing running! Don't forget to initialize them with `StartCoroutine()`, otherwise nothing will happen!

Comment: Thank you - I was thinking in terms of running code initialized by code, didn't have much experience with GameObjects and that they are already scripted to run simultainously if needed. I will try to base by code structure around interacting with GameObjects.

Comment: Alright! Running code initialized by code is a great usage for Coroutines, I updated my answer with an example and how it works!

Comment: Thank your for your huge help in understanding this. I'd give you more points if I could :)

Comment: Glad I could help you! :)